# Multiple domains on shared hosting with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like a domain to redirect to a subdirectory. From all the questions on SO, this is the most functional `.htaccess` setup I could come up with, but it's not quite right.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !other-domain-dir/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /other-domain-dir/$1 [L]
```

It works perfectly on the homepage. Navigating to `otherdomain.com` returns index.html as expected. But, if I go to `otherdomain.com/test`, I get redirected to `otherdomain.com/other-domain-dir/test/`, which loads the page correctly, but I do not want `other-domain-dir` to be visible. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `/test/` is a directory and `mod_dir` is adding a trailing slash first.

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/other-domain-dir/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /other-domain-dir/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?otherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/other-domain-dir/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /other-domain-dir/$1 [L]
```

Comment: In addition to what you suggested, I also added this above.

`# ADD TRAILING SLASH TO DIRECTORY IF NONE EXISTS`
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, Yes that trailing slash rule will also be fine.